# Is there any List data structure that provides ordering while adding?

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, sortedlist

I need a list data structure that sorts as soon as an item is added. Like `SortedSet` does it, just allowing duplicates. Is there something like this in the .NET framework?

I already checked the docs, but couldn't find anything. Can't believe that there's only `SortedSet` and `SortedList`, where in the latter case it's sorted on the key instead of an object property (I also don't want keys, just a list of objects of a given type sorted by a custom comparer)

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3423456) in duplicate. Your question is too broad, and reads more like a request for a recommendation of a particular data structure than a request for help with some _specific_ programming problem. It's not clear what you've tried so far, nor what other requirements you might have

Comment: @TimSchmelter: maybe you should look at the link I provided. Also, there are two other duplicates that are equally applicable to this question. Frankly, that there are so many possible approaches is the very definition of "too broad". That you would even have to ask why I consider it too broad is bewildering to me.

Comment: I also think it's a pity that the question got close, because the referred links do not really answer it, to me. As far as I can see the OP wants a autosorted generic list (which implies to me it implements IList<T>) and it seems there's no such thing in .NET built-in.
SortedSet<T> and SortedList<T> for example doesn't even have an indexer aka "this[index]".

Comment: `(which implies to me it implements IList<T>)` That clearly isn't possible @lidqy - since how would https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.insert?view=net-5.0 work?

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf Writing your own class which contains a `SortedList` internally (or `List` combined with `BinarySearch`) and exposes the operators you particularly want is likely your best bet. And make sure that the key is immutable. :)